# Border of Textbox not shown op GroupBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I use this code to change the color of the border of a textbox to red.

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e) {
      e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Brushes.Red, 3), 
        tb.Location.X-1, tb.Location.Y-1, tb.ClientRectangle.Width+ 5, 
        tb.ClientRectangle.Height + 5);
}
```

This works on a textbox that is directly on the Form but not when the textbox is in a groupbox. How should i do that ?

Comment: Have you tried creating your own user control that has a border so that you can easily change it?

Comment: No, i want to keep this as simple as possible, no extra controls, classes etc, the code i published does what it needs to only not on groupboxes, i can't see what difference it would make to do make a user control. In my book you should first work something out that works, then you still can make a control of it

Comment: you should subclass your textbox and draw it there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form's Paint event cannot scribble on the group box, it has its own window.  Windows are prevented from painting on each other.

You'll need to use the group box' Paint event.

Comment: that's it ! as simple as that, THANKS !!